# Traveling to UK and Ireland on Indian Passport BIVS

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, ireland

I am traveling to Ireland later this month and I had the following questions:

1. I am looking to enter Ireland from Belfast (taking a train from Belfast to Dublin on during end of May). I will be spending half a day in Dublin, a few days in Galway and the last day in Cork after which I will return to London. Since most of the places on the internet say that there is no immigration check between Northern Ireland and Ireland while traveling by train or bus, I am worried that I will not have an entry stamp on my passport. I hope this will not be a problem when I am exiting the country through Cork, or on subsequent return. What should I do in order to get my passport stamped?
2. I will be spending a week in England after that and returning to visit Dublin with my husband on in June once again. Will this be okay? I have a multiple entry BIVS visa with a validity of 6 months.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. My question is since I will be traveling from Belfast to Dublin, there will be NO stamp on my passport on entry. Hope this will not be a problem when I exit or return.